# Convert matrix of numbers (castable to Double) to matrix of Doubles

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I have a class that takes a 2-dimensional array as a parameter.

```
case class Matrix(matrix: Array[Array[Double]]) {

  def getRow(idx: Int): Array[Double] = matrix(idx)

  def getColumn(idx: Int): Array[Double] = {
    for{
      row <- matrix
    } yield row(idx)
  }
}
```

Turns out, in Scala it is not allowed to do something like this:

```
val arr = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
val matrix = Matrix(arr)
```

Compilation error:

> type mismatch;
> found   : Array[Array[Int]]
> required: Array[Array[Double]]

And I want to make a class where all matrices of types that are castable to double will implicitly be converted to a 2-dim array of doubles. And I can't wrap my head around it. Here's what I have already tried:

```
case class Matrix(matrix: Array[Array[Double]]) {

  implicit def convertToDouble(inputMatrix: Array[Array[Int]]): Array[Array[Double]] = {
    for{
      row <- matrix
    } yield row.map(_.toDouble)
  }

  def getRow(idx: Int): Array[Double] = matrix(idx)

  def getColumn(idx: Int): Array[Double] = {
    for{
      row <- matrix
    } yield row(idx)
  }
}
```

But it does not work either and the compiler still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply add a companion object, with the appropriate apply method:

```
object Matrix {
  def apply(matrix: Array[Array[Int]]): Matrix = {
    Matrix(matrix.map(_.map(_.toDouble)))
  }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
val arr = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
val matrix = Matrix(arr)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/CyNwxJxHQiG93Ad9olpDJQ).

Comment: yes, now it works for Ints as well, thanks. Still does not work for short, byte, etc. Of course, I can write apply methods for every castable-to-double type. But it seems like there should be a little bit more convenient approach for such kind of a problem.

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov yeah do not use plain **Arrays**, they are mutable, not real collections and invariant _(which is what makes this to fail)_. Use a real collection like **List**, **Vector** or **ArraySeq** instead.

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov, I wouldn't look for generic solutions for some primitives. Just implement for the few types you are interested.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ok, thanks, I made the class declaration this way: `case class Matrix(matrix: Vector[Vector[_ >: Numeric[_]]])` and it works. I guess it's more Scal-ish now :)

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov that doesn't do what you think it does. What exactly do you want? you want your class to work for any numeric type? Or just ensure that if you pass a matrix of **Ints** it will be upcasted to a matric of **Doubles**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez at first, I wanted to take any numeric 2-dim array and cast it to 2-dim double array inside of my class. But now, I suppose, I take any numeric 2-dim Vector (though, no casting to double inside) and it, unlike the Array type, allows me to easily create a Numeric-type (short, byte, int, double, float, whatever) matrix because of the Vector covariance. Am I right?

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov maybe [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Ni7h5qsCSpqBHeDmr81Z1Q/6) works as a draft for what you want to do. Note that, it uses _"advanced"_ concepts like **generics** and [**typeclasses**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).